# Delete a jpg file from host with php code

Tags: php, server, unlink

in this php ,i want get a "ID" and find the Img1 for this ID from database.(The url of the Img1 is stored in the database).
and then delete this file.but the img1 dont deleted

```
function delete(){

$connection = connectToDatabase();
$ID = $_REQUEST['ID'];

if($ID!==""){


    $result1 = mysqli_query($connection,"select Img1 from banners where ID='$ID' ");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
    $namefile1 = $row[0];//(in $namefile1 the url address of img1 is saved like this:http://bestabsd.com/bestfile/pics/jan18-11-28-20-46-36.jpg) 

    $files = glob($namefile1); 
 foreach($files as $file){
if(is_file($file))
unlink($file);}

    mysqli_close($connection);

}
```

Comment: You need an file path or exact path - not the URL pointing to your file

Comment: but i have the url address, how i can make path from that address?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** i edit my code to new for make a path, but the jpg dont deleted yet....

```
function delete(){

$connection = connectToDatabase();
$ID = $_REQUEST['ID'];

if($ID!==""){


    $result1 = mysqli_query($connection,"select Img1 from banners where ID='$ID' ");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
    $namefile1 = $row[0];
    $namefile11=str_replace("http://bestabsd.com/bestfile/pics/", "", $namefile1);
    $base_directory = '/home/bestabsd/public_html/bestfile/pics/';
    unlink($base_directory.$namefile11);

    mysqli_close($connection);

}else {
    print "null";
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to check if the file path is OK before executing ```unlink```. Take a look at ```file_exists```: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php.
Also make sure the ```$base_directory``` has a proper value.
You could use ```dirname``` to get the absolute path to your script's directory:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php